# What is the syntax in this forum to create keyboard-like key images?

Tags: discussion, editing

I found that some users type a keyboard button with a box around it such as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51726/how-to-restore-delete-key-functionality). I like to use this in my question, but do not know how. What do I have to type?